# How do I use a Button to run an Update Query?

Tags: sql-update

We have a large database in which we have multiple table that store data.  We input our customer logging rates into a form and would like to have the information update to our loadsliptbl as well as to our infoconverionratestbl withour haveing to go into a seperate update query and input that information again (already entered into the form).

The update query is as follows:

UPDATE Loggingtbl INNER JOIN Loadsliptbl ON Loggingtbl.LoggingId = Loadsliptbl.LoggingId SET Loadsliptbl.EstConvRate = 1.4289, Loadsliptbl.[LogRate-T] = 24.22
WHERE (((Loadsliptbl.Date) Between #5/19/2012# And #6/1/2012#) AND ((Loggingtbl.TM)="FJ3W66 312") AND ((Loadsliptbl.Stratum)="20-415P"));

WE have to enter the EstConvRate, LogRate-T, the date parameters, TM and Stratum on both the form and then in the update query.

How do I Automate this?

Shelly

Comment: Just a note on this, the form we are inputing to is based on the Loggingtbl as the main form and the Infor=Conversionratestbl for the subform.  Which could be the base of my problem, However because this update has multiple items that need to match such as being between the dates, the stratum, and the TM makes it more difficult for me to see the path I need to take.

Comment: Do you think this will work??                                       UPDATE Loggingtbl INNER JOIN Loadsliptbl ON Loggingtbl.LoggingId = Loadsliptbl.LoggingId SET Loadsliptbl.EstConvRate = InfoConversionLoggingRatestbl.EstConvRate, Loadsliptbl.[LogRate-T] = InfoConversionLoggingRatestbl.LogRate-T WHERE (((Loadsliptbl.Date) between InfoLoggingRatestbl.StartDate And InfoLoggingRatestble.EndDate)) AND ((Loadsliptbl.Stratum)=InfoConversionRatestbl.Stratum );